# iPhone playing songs not in any of my playlists

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, playlist

I share an iTunes account with 4 others in my family and we have different music taste. I have my own playlists but my iPhone (3GS) keeps playing music that is NOT on any of my playlists. I have checked them all. How do I delete them off my phone? I have no unwanted artists or albums selected under the music tab when syncing, I have checked all of my playlists, I do not have 'automatically fill free space with songs' ticked either. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings>General>Music.  
Turn off the "Show All Music" option

[image]